# Efficient data structure to get an ID

Tags: data-structures

I need an efficient data structure to generate IDs. The IDs should be able to be released using a method in the data structure. After an ID was released it can be generated again. The data structure must always retrieve the lowest unused ID.
What efficient data structure can be used for this?

Comment: are the id's bounded? what do you need in 'fast'? how fast should it be? does it have to be 'fast' on worst case or average case?

Comment: @amit: yes they are bounded until they are released. fast on the average case is enough(as long as it doesn't have apocalyptic cases) @roe: How will priority queue help? I can't keep all unbounded IDs in a queue.

Comment: Can't you just increment an integer and return that, with appropriate currency control.  If someone releases an integer back store that in another sorted data structure and return that.  If the list of returned integers is empty then your return is a simple as read, increment, write, return.  If the list of returned integers is not empty then just read, return and remove the int from the returned integers list.

Comment: @planetjones thats good one, make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just increment an integer and return that, with appropriate currency control. If someone releases an integer back store that in another sorted data structure and return that. If the list of returned integers is empty then your return is a simple as read, increment, write, return. If the list of returned integers is not empty then just read, return and remove the first int from the returned integers list